# Magento 2 : Call custom block html in breadcumbs

Tags: magento2, product, breadcrumbs, page-layouts

Is there any way to call `custom module block` in `breadcrumbs`. I want to call certain html in `product detail page's breadcrumbs`. I am adding following code to `catalog_product_view.xml`.

> companyname/module/view/template/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
  <body>
...
<referenceBlock name="breadcrumbs">
        <block class="Companyname\Module\Block\Product\View\test" name="product.view.test" template="Companyname_Module::product/view/test.phtml" >
    </referenceBlock>

...
 </body>
</page>
```

But this is not adding in breadcrumb.

**Note: I am using custom theme.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post goes into a good amount of detail on getting a template into another's block.

[How to override phtml file of a custom module in magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/170646/how-to-override-phtml-file-of-a-custom-module-in-magento-2)

In your case, you are looking to do a little bit of both, you want to have a custom phtml into the `breadcrumbs`, but you want it to be from your own block class. By doing the plug in, you can call a new template for the original block class, and then inside that custom class, do what ever logic you need to inject.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code for call custom module block in breadcrumbs

```
 <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('product.view.test'); ?>
```

**Or use:**

```
 <?php echo $block->getChildHtml(); ?>
```

Comment: This is not working for me.