# How to specify skin image path in Knockout HTML template?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, knockoutjs

I'm trying to add an icon image in the `Magento_Paypal/web/template/payment/paypal-express.html` template. The icon is located in `web/images`. I would like to use the equivalent of the following code, which works in email HTML templates, but not this particular template:

```
<img src="{{view url='images/icon-paypal.png'}}">
```

Since curly brace variables do not work in this HTML template, how do you reference an image that exists in the theme's `web/images` directory?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need to call the `function` into `js` from the template.

```
require.toUrl('images/icon-paypal.png');
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for -- accepted! Here's the final image tag for those interested: `<img data-bind="attr: { src: require.toUrl('')+'images/icon-paypal.png' }" alt="">`.

Comment: Wouldn't that be better as `require.toUrl('images/icon-paypal.png');`? I haven't tried it, I'm just presuming that works.

Comment: @BenCrook I can confirm that your suggestion works.

Comment: Thanks @Meogi, if anyone else can confirm it I'll update the answer. I'm too busy on Magento 1 to check it atm.

Comment: @BenCrook I checked and can confirm that your solution works

Comment: I've updated the answer to contain the cleaner method. Thanks

Comment: require.toUrl('')  gives us path of pub/static . what we should use for get 
baseurel/pub/media/ in ko html templates ?

Comment: can you guys check on this question? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/296357/how-to-add-an-icon-next-to-payment-method-for-amazon-pay

Comment: For anyone wondering, this also works for module images just add it to the start of the image path -  `require.toUrl('Vendor_Module/images/icon-paypal.png');`

Answer (score 4):

If you are trying to add just an image path in phtml file, you should follow below way,

```
<img src="<?php echo $block->getViewFileUrl('images/image.png') ?>">\
```

**To do this with Knockout way:**

Try adding a variable to window from *.phtml file:

```
<script>
  window.imgpath = '<?php echo $block->getViewFileUrl('images/image.png') ?>';
  </script>
```

and reading that variable from window:

```
  function someFunction() {
  var imgPath = window.imgpath;
  }
```

Change your image code :

```
<img alt="" data-bind="attr: { src: someFunction() } "/>
```

Comment: but that window path you must need to call into head part, so better to do using ko.

Answer (score 3):

create js variable in phtml

```
<script>
  var imgpath = '<?php echo $block->getViewFileUrl('images/image.png') ?>';
</script>
```

Now create new js function

```
getImagepaypal: function() {
                return window.imgpath;
            }
```

in you html file

```
 <img alt="" data-bind="attr: { src: getImagepaypal() } "/>
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how to create full js and html file in custom override and how to add that in xml?

Comment: did you want to override the magneto default js and html in your module?

Comment: yes i want to override "Magento_CheckoutAgreements" files phtml, js and html.

Comment: @SarfarajSipai follow this  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/170646/how-to-override-phtml-file-of-a-custom-module-in-magento-2

Comment: I know how to create/override module but i dont know how to override "js" and "html" in custom theme override so i want to know that.

Comment: @SarfarajSipai check the official documents http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/custom_js.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66860/discussion-between-sarfaraj-sipai-and-qaisar-satti).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in each magento require js files without any requirements - its coming from vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/page/js/require_js.phtml

```
require.s.contexts._.config.baseUrl
```