# How to bind the image in ko template

Tags: magento2.2.2, knockoutjs, html, media-images

I have image tag in phtml file ..

And also i got the value of images and media url from ajax call .

How to bind it like that in ko template

```
<img alt="<?php echo $sizeGuideImage->getAlt() ?>" class="img-responsive" data-src-base="<?php echo $this->getMediaUrl() ?>" data-src="<479:<?php echo 'sizeguide/small/' . $sizeGuideImage->getSmallImage() ?>, <767:<?php echo 'sizeguide/medium/' . $sizeGuideImage->getMediumImage() ?>, <1399:<?php echo 'sizeguide/large/' . $sizeGuideImage->getLargeImage() ?>, >1400:<?php echo 'sizeguide/extralarge/' . $sizeGuideImage->getExtraLargeImage() ?>" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the function into js from the template.

```
require.toUrl('')+'images/icon-paypal.png';
```

Addition: This can be written in a cleaner way:

```
require.toUrl('images/icon-paypal.png');
```

[Source](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/172722/how-to-specify-skin-image-path-in-knockout-html-template?rq=1) [How to specify skin image path in Knockout HTML template?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/172722/how-to-specify-skin-image-path-in-knockout-html-template?rq=1)

Comment: But i need  to frame img tag like                                                                                     data-src="<479:sizeguide/small/bra_size_calculator_365-x-228-30kb_1.jpg, <767:sizeguide/medium/bra_size_calculato_507-x-317-40-kb_1.jpg"