# How to Add an icon next to Payment Method for Amazon Pay?

Tags: magento2, css, payment-methods, phtml, knockoutjs

I have looked up a few similar question but can't figure how. 
It's the default amazon pay module that came with Magento 2
I'm editing this file

> /var/www/html/vendor/amzn/amazon-pay-module/view/frontend/web/template/payment/amazon-payment-widget.html

but it's not making an effect ( also did setup:upgrade, s:s:d, c:f ..)

```
/**
 * Copyright 2016 Amazon.com, Inc. or its affiliates. All Rights Reserved.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License").
 * You may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * A copy of the License is located at
 *
 *  http://aws.amazon.com/apache2.0
 *
 * or in the "license" file accompanying this file. This file is distributed
 * on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either
 * express or implied. See the License for the specific language governing
 * permissions and limitations under the License.
 */

<!-- ko if: (isPwaVisible) -->
    <!-- ko if: (isAmazonAccountLoggedIn) -->

        <div class="payment-method amazon-payment-method" data-bind="css: {'_active': (getCode() == isChecked())}">
            <div class="payment-method-title field choice">
                <input type="radio"
                       name="payment[method]"
                       class="radio"
                       data-bind="attr: {'id': getCode()}, value: getCode(), checked: isChecked, click: selectPaymentMethod, visible: isRadioButtonVisible()"/>
            <!--adding amazon pay logo-->
            <img data-bind="attr: { 'src': require.toUrl('images/ap-acceptance-medium.png') }" alt="amazon pay icon">
            <!--adding amazon pay logo-->
                <label data-bind="attr: {'for': getCode()}" class="label"><span data-bind="text: getTitle()"></span>
                </label>

            </div>
            <div class="payment-method-content">
                <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('messages') -->
                <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
                <!--/ko-->
                <div class="amazon-widget-container">
                    <div id="walletWidgetDiv" class="amazon-widget amazon-widget--payment" data-bind="afterRender: initPaymentWidget"></div>
                </div>

                <div class="checkout-agreements-block">
                    <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('before-place-order') -->
                    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
                    <!--/ko-->
                </div>

                <div class="actions-toolbar">
                    <div class="primary">
                        <button class="action primary checkout"
                                type="submit"
                                data-bind="
                                click: placeOrder,
                                attr: {title: $t('Place Order')},
                                css: {disabled: isPlaceOrderDisabled()},
                                enable: (getCode() == isChecked())
                                "
                                disabled>
                            <span data-bind="i18n: 'Place Order'"></span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    <!--/ko-->
<!--/ko-->
```