# Magento 2: How to override new_grid.phtml in Custom Module?

Tags: magento2, product, overrides, widget

I need to override `product/widget/new/content/new_grid.phtml` file in my custom module. Please tell me the possible ways to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To override phtml in custom module, please follow below mentioned answer, it will solve your issue:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/170652/84659